# How to show customer review on magento homepage with rating, customer profile picture?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1, review

I want show customer review on magento homepage with rating, customer profile on my magento 2 store. 
What is the best way to do that? Do you have any suggestion. Highly appreciated.